# Trying to rescript mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I wanted to move from mysql to mysqli_ , but I receive some errors.

```
Undefined index: Username in .. on line 8
Couldn't fetch mysqli in .. on line 8
Empty query in .. on line 9
```

This is part of my code

```
<?php
    include("config.php"); //including our config.php 
    include("auth.php");
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) //if session is set, so if user is logged in... 
    { 
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        $Username = $row['Username']; //selecting user name, change 'username' to your field name  
        $Headshots = $row['Headshots']; //selecting user money, change 'money' to your field name  
    $Mesaj2 = $row['Mesaj2'];
    $Mesaj3 = $row['Mesaj3'];
    $Mesaj4 = $row['Mesaj4'];
    $viplog = $row['viplog'];
                $sql2 = "SELECT Username, BanditsKilled FROM users order by BanditsKilled DESC LIMIT 5;";
        $con2=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
        $results2 =  array();
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con2,$sql2);

        $results2 = mysqli_fetch_all($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $output2 = '';

        foreach ($results as $row) {


    $output .= '  <li class="media"> <div class="media-left"> <a href="#">  <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user9.png" alt=""> </a> </div> <div class="media-body"> <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="">'. $row['Username'] . '</a></h4> <span>' . $row['BanditsKilled'] . '</span> playeri ucisi</div> </li>';
        }

}   

                $sql3 = "SELECT Username, pHour FROM users order by pHour DESC LIMIT 5;";
        $con3=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
        $results3 =  array();
        $result3 = mysqli_query($con3,$sql3);

        $results2 = mysqli_fetch_all($result3, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $output3 = '';

        foreach ($results2 as $row) {


    $output2 .= '  <li class="media"> <div class="media-left"> <a href="#">  <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user9.png" alt=""> </a> </div> <div class="media-body"> <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="">'. $row['Username'] . '</a></h4> <span>' . $row['pHour'] . '</span> ore jucate</div> </li>';
        }

}


                $sql4 = "SELECT Username, pAliveTime FROM users order by pAliveTime DESC LIMIT 5;";
        $con3=mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
        $results4 =  array();
        $result4 = mysqli_query($con5,$sql4);

        $results4 = mysqli_fetch_all($result4, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $output4 = '';

        foreach ($results4 as $row) {


    $output4 .= '  <li class="media"> <div class="media-left"> <a href="#">  <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user9.png" alt=""> </a> </div> <div class="media-body"> <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="">'. $row['Username'] . '</a></h4> <span>' . $row['pAliveTime'] . '</span> secunde in viata</div> </li>';
        }

    ?>
```

I want to specify that there are a lot of more $text = $['row'] but I didn't post them to avoid massive spamming.

Why it shows those errors? If I use my old mysql code, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: You check `$_SESSION['username']` and then access `$_SESSION['Username']`

Comment: So instead of accesing $_SESSION i should acces $_POST ?

Comment: I think it's more a case of always using the same element name - `'username'` with a lower case u.

Comment: That worked, but still: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli on line 8 and mysqli_query(): Empty query in on line 9.

Comment: Where is `$con` defined, you seem to be making a lot of database connections, you should just need the 1 connection.

Comment: In your one if your doing `mysqli_query($con,$sql)`, `$sql` is the result of the previous lines call to `$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems with this code...

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * 
                     FROM users 
                     WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
```

You are using `$sql` to run the query twice, I assume the second time is meant to fetch the data (using [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php))...

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * 
                     FROM users 
                     WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");    // lowercase u
if ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
```

Also not sure where `$con` is defined, maybe need...

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
```

as for the other times you call this, best to stick to 1 connection and re-use it.

Also further down you have...

```
$results2 = mysqli_fetch_all($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$output2 = '';

foreach ($results as $row) {
```

Which is retrieving the data into `$results2` and then using `$results`.

It's also worth looking into prepared statements as this offers a lot of advantages including security etc.

Comment: Con is defined in config.php

Comment: I have a problem now. My website shows red "unsecured' after what I moved from mysql to mysqli. What are the causes?

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment above, I make my comment here.
Maybe, instead of:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))...
```

you mean:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."'";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))...
```

Comment: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in

Comment: Fixed it. Now the error is mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in